# I am trying to convert my string formatted value to date type with format dd.MM.yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

```
this.Text = "22.11.2016"; 

DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

when I run it its give me error :

> Error.String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. An error occurred while processing your request

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);

Answer (score 3):

In your example you use slashes (`/`) to parse the date in `ParseExtract()` but in `this.Text` your date has dots (`.`) as separators.

Replace this line:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

by this one:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);
```

Also, you can change `this.Text` to use slashes and your code will be working.

Comment: when i insert this date to sql , now i have this error ,Error.Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @MahmoudOmar, I don't see any code where you do this. Your question is about parsing error not with `SQL`.

Comment: i select data from excel sheet and i have problem with date this date format like (22.11.2016)  when i insert this value in table give me this error (Error.Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string) , code is very big

Comment: @MahmoudOmar, to my mind you should ask a new question, because this one is not about inserting in table. This error is not the same as in this question

Comment: ok i will create new

Answer (score 3):

You can mention *several formats* allowing the delimeter to be either `.` or `/`:

```
  this.Text = "22.11.2016"; 

  var result = DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, 
    new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy" }, 
    null, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text is in this format `22.11.2016` and you're trying to parse from this format `22/11/2016`.

You have 3 options:

1. Change the `this.Text` format from `this.Text="22.11.2016;"` to `this.Text="22/11/2016";`
2. Change parsing method from `DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);` to `DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", null);`
3. You can force your desired format ( kind of ) by calling `Replace()` method : `DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text.Replace('.', '/'), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);`

Answer (score 0):

If your culture has a `.` as date separator, pass the culture

e.g.

```
this.Text = "22.11.2016";
DateTime dateTime =
    DateTime.ParseExact(this.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
```

Note that `/` is a custom format specifier for the localized date separator. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator)